# When trying to override plugin's function by theme, my filter executes two times, I want it to run only a single time

Tags: theme-development, filters

**Here's plugin function:**

```
function dokan_get_admin_commission_by($order, $seller_id)
{
    $saved_admin_fee = get_post_meta(dokan_get_prop($order, 'id') , '_dokan_admin_fee', true);
    if ($saved_admin_fee != '')
    {
        return apply_filters('dokan_order_admin_commission', $saved_admin_fee, $order);
    }
    $admin_commission = 10;
    return apply_filters('dokan_order_admin_commission', $admin_commission, $order);
}
```

**I have overwritten this function from theme's `functions.php` file:**

```
function dokan_get_admin_commission_by_overwrite( $admin_commission, $order) {
    return $admin_commission+1;
}
add_filter( 'dokan_order_admin_commission', 'dokan_get_admin_commission_by_overwrite', 10, 2 );
```

Theme filter is working fine, but it runs two times. So it increments the value two times. The reason it runs two times is because in the plugin, function `dokan_get_admin_commission_by` is called two times. I don't know how to run it a single time by theme's `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

### Probable cause of double increment:

The plugin function `dokan_get_admin_commission_by()` executes `apply_filters('dokan_order_admin_commission' ... )` twice, but both times it uses `return`, so the filter is **not** executing twice.

The probable cause of getting double increment is because, in the following CODE:

```
if ($saved_admin_fee != '')
{
    return apply_filters('dokan_order_admin_commission', $saved_admin_fee, $order);
}
```

the plugin is giving your theme filter `$saved_admin_fee` as `$admin_commission`, on the other hand, in the following CODE:

```
$admin_commission = 10;
return apply_filters('dokan_order_admin_commission', $admin_commission, $order);
```

the plugin is **always giving `10` as `$admin_commission` value** to the theme filter.

So, you may need to handle this same condition in your theme function.

Also, if the filter is executing twice, then it must be from somewhere else. In that case, you'll have to remove the filter once the theme function is executed.

### Example CODE fix for `functions.php`:

So your final theme CODE will be like:

```
function dokan_get_admin_commission_by_overwrite( $admin_commission, $order) {
    remove_filter( 'dokan_order_admin_commission', 'dokan_get_admin_commission_by_overwrite', 10, 2 );
    if ( $admin_commission === 10 ) {
        return $admin_commission + 1;
    }

    return $admin_commission;
}
add_filter( 'dokan_order_admin_commission', 'dokan_get_admin_commission_by_overwrite', 10, 2 );
```

Now this function should run only once and also increment with the proper condition checked.

> **Note:** if you are still confused, or need further assistance, then I'd suggest you to contact that plugin's support team.

Comment: Fayaz I have already tried all the above solutions, no any work for me...

Comment: still not working,check this screenshot for better to understand why filter run two times:  http://nimb.ws/eb5SUx

Comment: The plugin doesn't call the filter twice by those two lines. It uses the condition with `return`, so even though within the `dokan_get_admin_commission_by` function `apply_filters('dokan_order_admin_commission' .. )` is called twice, only one of these CODE will execute at a time. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes it uses condition, but after comment this code funcitons.php file code working fine...
 `if ($saved_admin_fee != '')
    {
        return apply_filters('dokan_order_admin_commission', $saved_admin_fee, $order);
    }`

Comment: Actually, i am looking for the solution, don't want to work on plugin files. Want to overwrite admin commission by theme functions.php

Comment: thanks for providing assistance, after use updated code the filter is not being run once